# Parent child relationship where a child can belong to different parent: design approach

Tags: database, database-design, amazon-redshift, rdbms, azure-synapse

i have a situation in which i am getting the data from multiple source like SourceA, SourceB, SourceC ...... SourceN. The data format or the content of each source can be different. now i need to process this data from multiple sources and generate a common output for each source example "Col1,Col3,Col3,SourceIdentifier,sourceUniqueID". now i need to add this output to some table lets call this table as processedoutput. now my question is 
1)  as you can see i need to identify in the Processedoutput table that which row belongs to which source and the uniqueID for each source (each source has one identity column as primary key) through these 2 columns i can get the unique row but i do not want to make 2 keys as the identifier, i just want a single key through which i can get the same answer. also i would not like to user the GUID column

2) if i am storing this data in the columnar database like redshift or AZUER data warehouse. will the 2 key as the identifier or unique identifier of a records will have any performance issue

3) as there are some BI tool like power BI which do not support multiple key as the join condition, how can i show the same data in say powerBI (note - i   can create a calculated column in powerBI and make the join as single key but i do not want to do that)

Thanks
Atul

Comment: I don't see anything about parents and children in your data or description. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry if i am not able to clarify myself. but all the source table are acting as the parent table and the processedoutput table is the child table which has multiple source tables

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical dimension building problem, where you want to translate business keys to surrogate keys.

Your staging table (probably the table you are calling commonoutput) has a two-part business key comprising SOURCE and ID.

Your target table (I think this is your processedoutput) needs to hold a surrogate key and your business key. The surrogate key is the ID that you will use to join to other tables, the business keys are still needed so that you can look up surrogate keys.

Your target table will look something like this:

- surrogate_key (give it a better name that reflects the business name of the table)
- source_id
- source_unique_id
- col1
- col2
- col3

You can probably use an IDENTITY column for the creation of new surrogate_key values. Identities are supported by both Redshift and Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

Like Ron said above,

1. Sources: 1..n: Source A, B, C ... N
2. Source format is different for each source.
3. Fixed Destination Schema i.e., Table schema for Dimension
4. Typical Dimension building in DW
5. If the dimension is like Customer, Product, then I also call it Master data problem.
6. You may need Xref Table and then Dimension Table.

Apart from Ron solution, Check articles or google similarly:

https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1636261

[Design a dimension with multiple data sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601124/design-a-dimension-with-multiple-data-sources)